# What layout, views, and design to use if I want to add draggable/movable objects?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

If I have to design an application that lets the user add playing cards to the screen and drag them to move them, what Views, layouts and elements should I use?

The cards can be added from any button or dragged from any other view.

Currently I add all cards in a GridView and they are flipped, added or deleted, my goal is to get rid of that GridView.

I've been looking for answers everywhere but I am not sure what to ask, I tried 'how to move objects inside a view' and others but no luck. I believe it should be done with canvas but before learning all that I want to know if I'm heading the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android supports many configurations of screens, you should first think if a game should be developed in the normal API of Android or using OpenGL.

If you use the normal API of Android, many layouts can be used, but I think the most suitable is the FrameLayout (use the margins of the children for making the being dragged to anywhere on the screen), and use the views you need according to what you need to show. For example, if you only show images for the cards, use ImageView for them.

EDIT: if the minimal API you support is 11 or above, you can use [**newer API commands**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) for drag&drop.

ANOTHER EDIT: if you wish to keep using a gridView , check out [**this solution**](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/pageddragdropgrid/).

Comment: Thank you, do you think the drag&drop API (which I did find when loking in the documentation) would better be used inside a FrameLayout as well? I won't use OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at the official documentation before hitting StackOverflow :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html